# Jenkins can't access shell alias

Tags: bash, jenkins, hudson

I have configured a Jenkins job to source a bash script that sources *another* bash script which adds an alias to the `.bashrc` of its user and sources the `.bashrc` itself, and then original script tries to use that alias (set by the second). However, it cannot seem to find the alias it has just created. I am not using any scripting plugins aside from using a "Send files or execute commands over SSH" build step to source the script.

The job does this:

```
source ./test_script.sh
```

`test_script.sh` looks like this:

```
echo "In test_script.sh"
echo $USER
echo $HOME
source ./setup_env.sh
echo "\nBack in test_script.sh"
alias foo
foo
```

And finally, `setup_env.sh` looks like this:

```
echo "\nIn setup_env.sh"
echo "alias foo=\"echo foobar\"" >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc 2>/dev/null
cat $HOME/.bashrc
```

The output I receive from the Jenkins job looks like this:

```
In test_script.sh
my_user
/home/my_user
\nIn setup_env.sh
...all of my bashrc...
alias foo="echo foo"
\nBack in test_script.sh
alias foo='echo foo'
./test_script.sh: line 7: foo: command not found
```

I don't understand why this is happening, when I can happily run it myself on the command-line and watch it succeed. Why can't Jenkins use the new alias, when it can obviously find it (as demonstrated by the output of the `alias foo` command)?

Comment: See [Why doesn't my Bash script recognize aliases?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1498/43764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\n` that is showing in the output of your `echo` commands
suggest this is not running under `bash`, as you may be expecting.

Please check the setting of your **jenkins** user
(or any other user that you run *Jenkins* with) -
especially the setting of the **default shell**.

To test this, add one of those lines at the beginning of your script:

```
env
```

or

```
env | grep -i shell
```

Should also consider making sure your scripts run under the correct shell,
by adding the "**shebang**" line as the first line in each script.
In the case of 'bash', for example, you should add the following first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(it is not a comment, despite what the auto-syntax-highlighter may think...)

Answer (score 20):

For anyone else who's having this problem, you may need to set the `expand_aliases` shell option, which seems to be off by default with Jenkins:

```sh
shopt expand_aliases # check if it's on
shopt -s expand_aliases # set expand_aliases option to true
shopt expand_aliases # it should be on now

# test with a simple alias, should print 1
alias x="python -c 'print 1'"
x
```

Comment: Couldn't have found this solution on my own. Thank you so much!